# Is this code a thread-safe one?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I want to process a flow of client requests. Each request has its special type. First I need to initialize some data for that type, and after this I can start processing the requests. When the client type comes for the first time, I just initialize the corresponding data. After this all the following requests of that type are processed using that data.

I need to do this in a thread-safe manner.

Here is a code I have written. Is it thread-safe?

```
public class Test {

    private static Map<Integer, Object> clientTypesInitiated = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Object>();

    /* to process client request we need to 
    create corresponding client type data.
    on the first signal we create that data, 
    on the second - we process the request*/

    void onClientRequestReceived(int clientTypeIndex) {
        if (clientTypesInitiated.put(clientTypeIndex, "") == null) {
            //new client type index arrived, this type was never processed
            //process data for that client type and put it into the map of types
            Object clientTypeData = createClientTypeData(clientTypeIndex);
            clientTypesInitiated.put(clientTypeIndex, clientTypeData);
        } else {
            //already existing index - we already have results and we can use them
            processClientUsingClientTypeData(clientTypesInitiated.get(clientTypeIndex));
        }
    }

    Object createClientTypeData(int clientIndex) {return new Object();}

    void processClientUsingClientTypeData(Object clientTypeData) {}
}
```

From one hand, ConcurrentHashMap cannot produce map.put(A,B) == null two times for the same A. 
From the other hand, the assignment and comparisson operation is not thread-safe.

So is this code is ok?
If not, how can I fix it?

UPDATE:
I have accepted the answer of Martin Serrano because his code is thread-safe and it is not prone to double initialization issue. But I would like to note, that I have not found any isssues with my version, posted as an answer below, and my version does not require synchronization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is not thread safe because

```
//already existing index - we already have results and we can use them
processClientUsingClientTypeData(clientTypesInitiated.get(clientTypeIndex));
```

has a chance of getting the "" value you temporarily insert in the put check.

This code could be made threadsafe thusly:

```
public class Test {

    private static Map<Integer, Object> clientTypesInitiated = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Object>();

    /* to process client request we need to 
       create corresponding client type data.
       on the first signal we create that data, 
       on the second - we process the request*/

void onClientRequestReceived(int clientTypeIndex) {
    Object clientTypeData = clientTypesInitiated.get(clientTypeIndex);
    if (clientTypeData == null) {
        synchronized (clientTypesInitiated) {
          clientTypeData = clientTypesInitiated.get(clientTypeIndex);
          if (clientTypeData == null) {
              //new client type index arrived, this type was never processed
              //process data for that client type and put it into the map of types
              clientTypeData = createClientTypeData(clientTypeIndex);
              clientTypesInitiated.put(clientTypeIndex, clientTypeData);
          }
        }
    }
    processClientUsingClientTypeData(clientTypeData);
}

Object createClientTypeData(int clientIndex) {return new Object();}

void processClientUsingClientTypeData(Object clientTypeData) {}
```

}

Comment: I think you need an `else` before the `processClientUsingClientTypeData`.

Comment: This is also not thread-safe! Look: one thread executes get, compares against null, steps into if, then another thread does the same, then one assigns to clientTypeData and eventually returns from the method, but another thread overrides the clientTypeData.

Comment: @Krzysztof what is unsafe?  like I said, _if_ you don't mind sometimes executing createClientTypeData more than once, this is fine.  in the case you describe, the second thread would just replace the result from the first one.  presumably since any request could trigger the initialization, then it will produce the same results everytime.  if initialization is _really_ expensive, then more complexity can be added to avoid that.

Comment: @MartinSerrano Look: null in the map, two threads execute `onClientRequestReceived`, both call `get` retrieving that null and get into `if`. **There**, once in `if`, both create an instance. Thats bad. One creates and puts first, leaves `if` and operates on data. Then second one creates another instance, puts assuming there is still null, what overrides previous value. And then processes this new instance.

Comment: @Gray No `else` is needed there assuming data processing is also needed even if it was just created.

Comment: @Krzysztof, i agree.  that is exactly what would happen.  but that does not mean it is unsafe.  if this data structure is acting like a cache (my presumption) then this is not unsafe, just potentially wasteful.

Comment: If there really is no interference between calls, then what is all this 'thread-safing' for? I'd use ThreadLocal in that case. However quoting the question: <<When the client type comes for the first time, I just initialize the corresponding data. After this all the following requests of that type are processed using **that data**.>> I assume that means the only created instance.

Comment: fair enough.  i've updated my example so that initialization only occurs once.  it still has the benefit of not needing to synchronize once initializations have occurred.

Comment: Much better now. Looks more complex in code, but is really efficient once initialized. +1

Comment: Oh yeah, I just mentioned double-checked locking and its here! :) Probably thats the best option, Martin, but please comment on my option below. Krzysztof, you got the point, I cannot run the initialization code for several times.

Comment: @KutaBeach, sorry I cannot comment yet!  but your solution has the flaw that if an initialization has started but not finished and a new request comes in then isInitStarted will not be 0 and isInitFinished will be 0, so that request will fall through and do nothing.

Comment: Martin, you are right, actually my question doesn't specify the behaviour of threads that arrived during the data initialization, so we can add the third "if" and wait there, or just fall through, anything goes.

Answer (score 3):

No, I don't think it is still thread-safe.

You need to wrap put operation in a synchronized block.

As per [javadoc for ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

> Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so may overlap with update operations (including put and remove).

Comment: it's not true for ConcurrentMap, he still can have it thread-safe and without any synchronization, which makes ConcurrentMap obsolete.

Comment: @jdevelop: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: He should use putIfAbsent method of ConcurrentMap

Comment: @Nambari I believe the "may overlap" in your quote means "they are designed to be safe to overlap", not "can but shouldn't overlap".  If that was the case, it would be redundant to say so, since that can happen with any data object, not just concurrent data object.

Comment: According to docs, get will return the results of finished updates, so if one put operation is still on it will return nothing and in our case it will start second update procedure.

Answer (score 2):

you should use putIfAbsent here, semantics of this operation is similar to CAS, and it is atomic for sure. And since it it atomic - then you don't have a problem with internal assignments and comparisons.

The current code is not thread-safe.

Comment: Wouldn't putIfAbsent require creating data before checking if there is anything? Mostly there would be, so it involves many unnecessary initializations.

Comment: Good idea, but indeed, as Krzysztof said, I'll have to run init procedure for several times in this case.

Comment: instead of putting an actual object - put Future, and you're safe.

Answer (score 1):

ConcurrentHashMap is created not to use synchronized block, although using it as a lock for synchronized block is ok, but not efficient. If you have to use `ConcurrentHashMap`, a correct usage is as follows;

```
private static Map<Integer, Object> clientTypesInitiated = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Object>();

void onClientRequestReceived(int clientTypeIndex) {
    Object clientTypeData = clientTypesInitiated.get(clientTypeIndex);
    if (clientTypeData == null) {
        Object newClientTypeData = createClientTypeData(clientTypeIndex);
        clientTypeData = clientTypesInitiated.putIfAbsent(clientTypeIndex, newClientTypeData);
        // if clientTypeData is null, then put successful, otherwise, use the old one
        if (clientTypeData == null) {
            clientTypeData = newClientTypeData;
        }
    }
    processClientUsingClientTypeData(clientTypeData);
}
```

To be honest, the above code might create `clientTypeData` multiple times (because of race condition) although it does not use `synchronized` block. Therefore, you should measure how expensive it is to create `clientTypeData` and if it is so expensive that it overshadow not using `synchronized` block, then you don't even need to use `ConcurrentHashMap`. Use normal `HashMap` and `synchronized` block.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not, if you need the whole method to be thread safe
declare it as synchronized, or use a synchronized block to 
put your critical code.

Comment: Why?  You need to provide information not just respond to the simple question.

Comment: in order to be thread safe, for basic information, google is your best friend
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Comment: You are missing my point.  _I_ know the answer.  SO answers are for posterity and to be google _destinations_ not to point people to google.  Your answers will not be up-voted unless they provide more information.

Comment: if you know it, why do you ask? i'm not here for points, the question was "is this code thread safe?", i answered, and explained what would do it thread safe, this guy obviously knows the concept, otherwise he would never ask this question, i wont spend my energy explaining how thread synchronization works, when there are literally hundreds of documents explaining it. If you don't like my answer, you can always post your own or improve this one.

Comment: @fer13488 A Java concurrent hash map does not need to have a synchronized block to be thread safe.  However, even though the underlying data structure is thread safe, the algorithm on top of it may have orders of execution which may result in bad state.  Using a synchronized block defeats the purpose of using a thread safe data structure.

Answer (score 0):

The current code is not thread safe since a context switch can occur between the if and the next put. you need to make `clientTypesInitiated` as type ConcurrentHashMap and not the interface Map. And then use the [putIfAbsent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent%28K,%20V%29) method

Answer (score 0):

I think the code doesn't work as intended at all. Look:

```
void onClientRequestReceived(int clientTypeIndex) {
     // the line below ensures the existing data is lost even if was not null
    if (clientTypesInitiated.put(clientTypeIndex, "") == null) {
        Object clientTypeData = createClientTypeData(clientTypeIndex);
        clientTypesInitiated.put(clientTypeIndex, clientTypeData);
    } else {
        processClientUsingClientTypeData(clientTypesInitiated.get(clientTypeIndex));
    }
}
```

I guess you rather wanted a get method call in there.

I'd suggest such an approach:

```
void onClientRequestReceived(int clientTypeIndex) {
    Object clientTypeData;
    synchronized (clientTypesInitiated) {
        if ((clientTypeData = clientTypesInitiated.get(clientTypeIndex)) == null) {
            clientTypeData = createClientTypeData(clientTypeIndex);
            clientTypesInitiated.put(clientTypeIndex, clientTypeData);
        } 
    }
    processClientUsingClientTypeData(clientTypeData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

putIfAbsent works great, but sometimes it will require initialization repeated for several times.
Synchronized block with double-checked locking probably can solve this problem.

But here is another option based on AtomicIntegerArrays:

```
public class Test {

    private static Map<Integer, Object> clientTypesInitiated = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Object>();

    private static final int CLIENT_TYPES_NUMBER = 10;
    private static AtomicIntegerArray clientTypesInitStarted = new AtomicIntegerArray(CLIENT_TYPES_NUMBER);
    private static AtomicIntegerArray clientTypesInitFinished = new AtomicIntegerArray(CLIENT_TYPES_NUMBER);

    void onClientRequestReceived(int clientTypeIndex) {

        int isInitStarted = clientTypesInitStarted.getAndIncrement(clientTypeIndex);
        int isInitFinished = clientTypesInitFinished.get(clientTypeIndex);

        if (isInitStarted == 0) {
            //new client type index arrived, this type was never processed
            //process data for that client type and put it into the map of types
            Object clientTypeData = createClientTypeData(clientTypeIndex);
            clientTypesInitiated.put(clientTypeIndex, clientTypeData);
            clientTypesInitFinished.getAndIncrement(clientTypeIndex);
        } else if (isInitFinished > 0) {
            //already existing index - we already have results and we can use them
            processClientUsingClientTypeData(clientTypesInitiated.get(clientTypeIndex));
        }
    }

    Object createClientTypeData(int clientIndex) {
        return new Object();
    }

    void processClientUsingClientTypeData(Object clientTypeData) {
    }
}
```

Any opinions?

Comment: I think you should consider to develop more object-oriented code. Using `Object` reference is not a good looking solution. Create an abstract class ClientData and derive from it implementing concrete classes. Create a factory class for those that instantiates 'em depending on `request.class`. Code that has type enumerations and indexing in general is difficult in maintenance and extending.

Comment: Sorry for a mess, Krzysztof, Object is just some dummy to be shown as ClientData, of course it shouldn't be like this. As for classes - actually each client type is just an index of resource, client types  dont differ at all. I need to init some resource before processing clients that relate to that resource. Yes, it would be better to write resourceIndex instead of clientType.

Comment: And referring the actual code now, I'm afraid it's buggy. Look: the first thread executes into `if`. The second one runs through the method, skips first `if`. Then it fails on second comparison and also **skips `else if`**, thus effectively does nothing.

Comment: Yes, exactly, Krzysztof. We have to do something in a case when the second thread arrived while the first one is still initializing the data. We can put a third if for that case and wait in that if. But I decided just to skip this request.

Comment: Waiting is possible for a thread, when there is a monitor object to wait on. Such object is automatically generated by JVM when entering synchronized block. Synchronized gets some kind of parameter in parentheses, which is the object to create monitor for. You can't effectively synchronize threads without monitors in Java.