# Is this Singleton a thread-safe one?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, singleton, atomic

Basing on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483487/is-this-code-a-thread-safe-one), I put down an interesting version of Singleton pattern which implementation is based on AtomicIntegers.

The questions are:

- is this implementation correct and thread-safe, and generally is it possible to use Atomic Variables for thread synchronization and management?
- Additional question: if this implementation is thread-safe, do I really need a `volatile` modifier for instance variable?

```
public class StrangeSingleton
{

    private StrangeSingleton() {};

    private static volatile Object instance;

    private static AtomicInteger initCounter = new AtomicInteger();
    private static AtomicInteger readyCounter = new AtomicInteger();

    static Object getInstance()
    {

        if (initCounter.incrementAndGet() == 1)
        {
            instance = new Object();

            readyCounter.incrementAndGet();

            return instance;
        }
        else if (readyCounter.get() == 1)
        {
            return instance;
        }
        else
        {
            //initialization not complete yet.
            //write here some logic you want:               
            //sleep for 5s and try one more time,
            //or throw Exception, or return null..

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: added the private constructor, but its not the point.

Comment: You are missing the private constructor !

Comment: How can it be a singleton when anybody can call `new StrangeSingleton()`. Create a private constructor that takes no arguments.

Comment: You could use `AtomicBoolean` instead of `AtomicInteger`.  Use `compareAndSet()`.

Comment: @Santosh You can create as many StrangeSingleton as you want, there will only be one `instance` object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> is this implementation is correct and thread-safe, and generally is it possible to use Atomic Variables for thread synchronization and management?

Its is but it usually more complicated and cpu intensive as you need to busy wait to respond to changes quickly.

> Additional question: if this implementation is thread-safe, do I really need a volatile modifier for instance variable?

In this case you don't because AtomicInteger contain volatile fields which will ensure correct happens-before/happens-after behaviour.

---

Of course you could just use an enum which is thread safe and much simpler ;)

```
enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;
}
```

Comment: Peter, how does this compare with usual double-check locking mechanism (from performance point of view) ?

Comment: Double check locking would be faster than checking two AtomicXxxxx. Using an `enum` is the fastest as it doesn't need a volatile field and no checking.

Comment: @Santosh Double-locking also isn't necessarily safe on all platforms for 1.4 and earlier due to some implementation semantics. ([Wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java)) This isn't a problem in 5+. Also, +1

Comment: @Brian I haven't used Java 1.4 for 8 years so I forget these things. In fact I didn't know it could be a problem until I was already using Java 5.0 ;)

Comment: @Brian, thanks for link. I guess if your scenario permits then initializing the singleton object in a private static variable at declaration time is the safest bet.

Comment: Thanks, Peter, you are right, the only disadvantage of your version is the absence of lazy-loading, while the double-checked locking singleton has it. And what about exception-handling in your option?

Comment: The INSTANCE isn't loaded until it is used the first time. Its just as lazy loaded as the alternatives.

Comment: @KutaBeach Check out the Wikipedia article I linked. Inner classes (or in this case, an inner enum) are loaded only when they're first referenced, not with the enclosing class.

Answer (score 2):

> is this implementation correct and thread-safe, and generally is it possible to use Atomic Variables for thread synchronization and management?

Yes, but for the `readyCounter` variable you should probably use a [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), like this:

```
private static AtomicInteger initCounter = new AtomicInteger();
private static CountDownLatch readyCounter = new CountDownLatch(1);

static Object getInstance()
{

    if (initCounter.incrementAndGet() == 1)
    {
        try {
            instance = new Object();
            return instance;
        } finally {
            readyCounter.countDown();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        readyCounter.await();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Calling *await()* also solves the initialization race condition. (I also added a try-finally block to avoid deadlocks on a constructor exception.)

> Additional question: if this implementation is thread-safe, do I really need a volatile modifier for instance variable?

No, not if you call the relevant `AtomicInteger` or `CountDownLatch` functions before accessing the instance variable.  Look for *happens-before* in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 0):

Thread **T1** may be suspended on `instance = new Object();`, **T2** will then hit the `else{}` block since `readyCounter` hasn't been incremented yet. Thtat is not quite correct since initialization **has** completed, what's lagging behind is the state book-keeping

Answer (score 0):

I would rather do one `synchronized` block in your `getInstance()` method. This is sufficient. You don't need these strange counters which are also not so safe as @David noticed.